# JQuery Select text within br and td in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the JQuery right to select the text from the following html structure:

```
<TABLE class=ms-formtable>
<TBODY>
<TR></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR>
<TD><H3><NOBR>Select this text</NOBR></H3></TD>
<TD></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Another thing: I personally am not a big fan of using the <nobr> tag use white-space:nowrap; in css in stead. Check out http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/nobr for more info

Answer (score 4):

#### simple selector

```
$('nobr').text();
```

#### more explicit selector

```
$('table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr > td > h3 > nobr').text();
```

**[An example to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/VU7NE/)**

Comment: Will $('table.ms-formtable nobr').text() specify the class? As there is more than one table in the page?

Comment: to basically walk the dom just keep chaining the html elements in the query i guess...

Comment: However be carefull when using special characters when using .text() as it will replace them with entities. If you don't want that I think you can use .html()

Comment: not sure if this does the same thing...? $('table.ms-formtable > nobr').text()

Comment: @nav- yes, `table.ms-formtable` will select `<table>` elements that have the CSS class `ms-formtable`

Comment: @nav - `$('table.ms-formtable > nobr')` does not do the same thing. Using `>` implies that the following selector is a direct descendent, which `<nobr>` is not. Omitting the `>` simply selects any descendent `<nobr>` of a `<table>` with CSS class `ms-formtable`

Comment: @Russ one final question when using $('table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr > td > h3 > nobr').text(); - how does the jquery know to select the 6th TR element?

Comment: thinking that might work... $('table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr:eq(5) > td > h3 > nobr').text();

Comment: @nav- it doesn't know to select the 6th element - imagine each selector from right to left acting as a filter. What you're saying to the DOM is "I want to select all `<nobr>` elements that are direct descendents of `<h3>` elements that are each in turn, direct descendents of `<td>` elements that are each in turn, direct descendents of `<tr>` elements that are each in turn, direct descendents of `<tbody>` elements that are each in turn, direct descendents of `<table>` elements".

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of ways of doing that. Is this the only table with that class name? My guess is `$('table.ms-formtable nobr').text()`, but it depends on the rest of the HTML, because this could select more than one element's text.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps use an ID to specify your H3 tag and therefore be able to select it using something like `$('#textToSelect').text()`.

That way you could be absolutely sure which text you were targeting on the page.