# jQuery to select text from HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking to get the HTML of the page search for some text and then select the element it belongs to with jQuery. Unfortunately there are no unique IDs for the elements.

Comment: Is this the same issue that you [asked about earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281421/jquery-select-text-within-br-and-td-in-table)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find text string using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

Comment: @patrick not quite before the text sat within a class and i could walk the dom ; @Gert very similar except i want the parent element that contains the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
<div><span>some text</span></div>
```

Then, to get only the `span` when you do the search, do this:

```
var elements = $('body *').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $(this).text().indexOf("some text") != -1;
}).parent();
```

If the text is found elsewhere, `elements` will contain the other elements as well. For example:

```
<div><span>some text</span><p>some text</p><strong>not the same text</strong></div>
```

Results will contain the `span` and the `p` elements.

A final example:

```
<div>some text<span>some text</span><p>some text</p><strong>not the same text</strong></div>
```

Now results will have the `div` too, as it is the direct parent of the text node (i.e. `some text`)

Comment: @nav - which part of $(...).contents().filter(...).parent(); isn't jQuery?

Comment: @scunliffe: I think he means the `this.nodeType` part. The rest is jQuery though :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this

```
var element = $('*:contains("search text")');
```

Comment: this is going to select all the parents too, all the way up to the `<body>` element (because technically they do contain that string)

Comment: and then use `.each()` to loop through the elements.